# Плюсы и минусы от своего сайта

Tags: seo

Произвожу мебель. Продаю её через площадки объявлений. Что в перспективе выгоднее: свой сайт или раскрученный ВКонтакте или Avito? Какие плюсы и минусы. Что рациональнее? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вопрос немного не о программировании, очень сомневаюсь что верстальщики или прогеры дадут вам совет . по ведению бизнеса

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. Поставьте на разных площадках разные телефоны и узнаете, откуда приходит больше запросов. :-)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что на ruSO принято задавать вопросы связанные с программированием.

Answer (score 1):

Выгоднее все, что дает конверсию.

Спрашивать лучше на на сео форумах - например, на cy-pr.com, webmasters.ru, sbup.com и тд.

Имея свой сайт (качественный, и не на конструкторе), вы являетесь полным хозяином его и контента да и домена (при надлежащем оформлении, что является дополнительным активом, со значительной свободой маневра).
Подключив грамотную стратегию на Google Ads (бывшее Google AdWords) и Яндекс директе + естественное и сео-продвижение, Вы оптимально сможете охватить возможную аудиторию потенциальных покупателей - конечно, конкуренция есть везде.

И еще - сегодня не иметь сайт в бизнесе является моветоном - это тоже следует учитывать (плюс использование сайта в печатной продукции - визитках, флаерах, рекламе и т.д.).